# Autologin root user without login and password window

Tags: raspbian

I've running latest version of Raspbian.

I edited the file `/etc/systemd/system/autologin@.service` and changed the one occurrence of `pi` in that file to `root`.

I edited the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and changed `autologin-user=pi` in that file to `autologin-user=root`.

And I've used `sudo raspi-config` --> Boot Options --> Desktop Autologin but after rebooting I'm still asked to enter my username and password.

Comment: Can you login as root manually? By default Raspbian (and most Debian distributions) DO NOT have a root login.

Comment: Why do you want to auto login as root?

Comment: This is a bad idea from a security perspective. It puts mot only your Pi and its' data at risk, but every device connected to your network.

Comment: @SteveRobillard That is somewhat true, assuming that (1) the Pi is accessible via the network, and (2) the `pi` user doesn't have passwordless `sudo` which makes it equalt to `root` security-wise. I used to have autologin as root on a board I used for hardware experiments: not having to deal with permissions actually saves some time.

Comment: If I read this in a year: what is the last version Raspbian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passwordless `root` login on Raspbian is disabled in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin`:

```
auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
```

Replace that line with a rule which would allow `root`. For example

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user = root
```

You could also authorize passwordless login for users of a certain group. For instance, create an `autologin` group and add the `root` user to it:

```
groupadd -r autologin
gpasswd -a root autologin
```

Then specify the following rule, (again, in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin`):

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup autologin
```

If you have further problems, post your `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`